# AngularJs 1: How to inject a service to a controller from the directive declaration

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, directive, reusability

I've created a directive for managing (creating/updating/deleting) comments on customers in my application.
Now I'd like the exact same comment functionality (look and feel) on users, so the only thing I need to do is replace my *CustomersService* with my *UsersService*.
Both services have the same methods for "crud-ing" comments (I would make both implement an *ICommentsService* interface if possible in javascript).

My question is how can I in the best possible way reuse my already created View and Controller so I don't have to duplicate code?

My initial approach is to create two separate directives (*CustomerComments* and *UserComments*) that reference the same view and controller, but injecting a *CustomersService* or a *UsersService* respectively. The problem I'm facing with this, is how to keep the "DI-definition" in the directive declaration whilst having the controller in a separate file...?

This is my directive declaration:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myComments', [
    function() {
        'use strict';
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                commentId: '='
            },
            templateUrl:'mycomments.html',
            controller: 'CommentsCtrl',  //<-- How to define injected objects here?
        };
    }
]);
```

...and this is my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('CommentsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$q',
    'CustomersService',   //<-- These "DI-objects" should be defined in the directive declaration
    function ($scope, $q, commentsService) {

        $scope.addComment = function(comment){
            commentsService.addComment(comment);
        };


        $scope.getComment = function(commentId){
            retur commentsService.getComment(commentId);
        };

        //...etc...
    }
]);
```

Or are there better ways to solve this?

Comment: _"How to define injected objects here?"_ - The same way as below.

Comment: Thanks @zeroflagL, but I haven't been able to get the syntax right when the controller is defined as an inline function in the directive declaration.
A little code snippet would be much appreciated...! :)

Comment: Your `templateUrl:mycomments.html'`, is missing a starting single quote. It should be `templateUrl: 'mycomments.html'`

Comment: Thanks @JohnF. - I've edited the sample code now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you do not explicitly register a directive's controller. That is somewhere you would have:

```
function CommentsCtrl($scope, $q, commentsService) {
```

And in your directive(s):

```
controller: ['$scope','$q','CustomersService', CommentsCtrl]
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - exactly what I was looking for!
But I'm wondering if this would work even after minification? 
I mean, my guess is that the minification process would "obfuscate" the function name and the controller definition differently and hence break the code...?